# if you use useRef to get a reference to a dom node, to get for example its value, does that mean that is an uncontrolled component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning to use use refs for the first time, and they say that it is normally used to get a reference from a dom node, for example get a value from the node. Would this make it an uncontrolled component?

isnt it "better" to use controlled components over references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refs are used to persist values between renders, without triggering any re-renders. This is typically used for things like managing focus, where you need access to the underlying DOM node. Don't use Refs to get values from nodes, which can be done declaratively. As a general rule of thumb, [don't overuse refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs).

To get a value from a node, it is best to create a controlled component. https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Comment: alright, so i should used it more to set focus on inputs that to get values.. thanks!